# how to apply different operators on two arrays with differents in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, operators, np

I have two arrays, each of them is composed by a pair of two integer (int1,int2). I want to compute a sum only on the first values of the pair of each array, and i want to apply a multiplication(for instance) on the second values.
Clearly, if i write this code:

```
tab1=np.array([(1,2),(1,5),(0,6)])
tab2=np.array([(0,7),(1,4),(0,2)])
tab3=tab1+tab2
tab4=tab1*tb2
```

the result of tab3 will be
    tab3=array([[1, 9],[2, 9],[0, 8]])

The sum was applied also in the second part. but i want to obtain (1+0),(1+1),(0+0), thus: 
    tab3=array([1,2,0])

Is it possible to have this result without do a loop on the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can index to get the appropriate elements:

```
>>> tab1 = np.array([(1,2),(1,5),(0,6)])
>>> tab2 = np.array([(0,7),(1,4),(0,2)])
>>> tab1
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 5],
       [0, 6]])
>>> tab1[:,0]
array([1, 1, 0])
>>> tab1[:,1]
array([2, 5, 6])
```

and thus

```
>>> tab3 = tab1[:,0] + tab2[:,0]
>>> tab4 = tab1[:,1] * tab2[:,1]
>>> tab3
array([1, 2, 0])
>>> tab4
array([14, 20, 12])
```

Comment: yes, it's the same procedure in Matlab for instance!!i had forgotten. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#Calculates the adding and the multiplication
t=map((lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]*y[1])) , tab1,tab2)
#Splits the result
tab3,tab4 = zip(*t)
```

It must be noted that when using map, the loop is implicit but still occurs as internal magic.